# Rails 3 + ActiveAdmin: How to make a user save two resources dependent on each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, activeadmin

I have 2 models, one is called Hotel and one is called HotelInfo.

When a user saves an Hotel resource in ActiveAdmin I want it to force the user to fill out the form for HotelInfo as well before it can be saved.

If possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example code that how to add two models together in active admin.

```
  form do |f|

    f.inputs "Hotel" do
      f.input :name
    end

    f.inputs "Hotel Information", :for => [:hotel_info, f.object.hotel_info || HotelInfo.new] do |hotel_info_form|
      hotel_info_form.input :telephone
    end

    f.buttons
  end
```

Comment: Thx, I tried this but I always get the NameError: uninitialized constant Hotel::HotelInfos ... it should work when it saves under Hotel::HotelInfo ... but my form options have to be :hotel_infos, f.object.hotel_infos ... don't know how to fix this.

Comment: nvm, got it... I had a has_one :hotel_infos in my hotel model instead of has_one :hotel_info

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `fields_for` helper to have both resources on the same form. Make sure your parent object has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotelinfo` set.